# A class containing 3 objects, which have pointers to each other, and an initialisation list to pass references to those objects. ERROR

Tags: c++, class, pointers, header, initialization

`Agent.h`:  //#include "Genetics.h" "Sensors.h" "Effectors.h"

```
class C_Agent
{
public:

    C_Agent();

    C_Genome Genome;
    C_Sensors Sensors;
    C_Effectors Effectors;
    s_agentParameters parameters; 
};
```

`Agent.cpp`: //#include "Agent.h"

```
C_Agent::C_Agent() 
: parameters(), Sensors(& parameters), Effectors(& parameters),
  Genome(& Sensors, & Effectors)
{ 
    //setup parameters
    Effectors.p_Genome = & Genome; 
}
```

`Sensors.h`: //#include "Genetics.h"

```
class C_Sensors
{
  public:
    s_agentParameters * p_parameters;
    C_sensors(s_agentParameters * p_parametersRef);
};
```

`Sensors.cpp`: //#include "Sensors.h"

```
C_Sensors::C_Sensors(s_agentParameters * p_parametersRef)
: p_parameters(p_parametersRef) {}
```

`Effectors.h` //#include "Genetics.h"

```
class C_Effectors
{
public:
    s_agentParameters * p_parameters;
    C_Genome * p_Genome;                               //forbids declaration w/ no type
    C_Effectors(s_agentParameters * p_parametersRef);
};
```

`Effectors.cpp`: //#include "Effectors.h"

```
C_Effectors::C_Effectors(s_agentParameters * p_parametersRef)
: p_parameters(p_parametersRef) {}
```

`Genetics.h`: //#include "Sensors.h" "Effectors.h"

```
class C_Genome
{
public:
    C_Sensors * p_Sensors;                             //forbids declaration w/ no type
    C_Effectors * p_Effectors;                         //forbids declaration w/ no type
    C_Genome(C_Sensors * p_C_SensorsRef, C_Effectors * p_C_EffectorsRef);
};
```

`Genetics.cpp`: //#include "Genetics.h" "Sensors.h" "Effectors.h"

```
C_Genome::C_Genome(C_Sensors * p_C_SensorsRef, C_Effectors * p_C_EffectorsRef)
: p_Sensors (p_C_SensorsRef),  p_Effectors (p_C_EffectorsRef) {}
```

When I try to compile this, I get 6 errors of "'class_name' does not name a type" and 6 errors of " ISO c++ forbids declaration of 'class_name' with no type". I also have code in main that attempts to initialize some C_Agent objects.

Comment: I would suggest putting back in how you are including your files.  The error is probably there.

Comment: Be more specific about what line(s) the error messages appear on and what error messages you get.

Comment: Warning: Order of the initalizers at the beginning of a constructor does *not* affect the order in which the members are constructed.  That depends on the order they are declared in the class.  So for example, if you want to pass `&parameters` to other members in the `C_Agent` constructor, you should probably move the declaration of `parameters` before the other members.

Comment: As I was adding the headers I realized that there was an include I had forgot to remove, and then doing so fixed all the 'does not name a type errors.' Now only the 'forbids declaration' errors are left. Unfortunately reordering C_Agent members didn't help.

Comment: added the line where the errors occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a circular dependency, you will need a forward declaration of at least one of the class names somewhere.

Comment: I added forward declarations to effectors.h and genetics.h, since that's where the remaining errors were coming from, and it fixed the problem.